# Automated CSS regression testing using HTTP verbs

Tags: css, phantomjs, automated-tests, regression-testing, backstop.js

I'm about to set up automated CSS regression with a tool like:

- [Phantom CSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS)
- [Backstop.js](https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS)

These look like good tools, but I want to test URLs using verbs. For example, I want to make a POST request with some data and run the test against that. This does not appear to be possible with any of the above tools. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since PhantomCSS depends on CasperJS, here is the hint how the `CasperJS.prototype.download()` method could be used: https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/modules/casper.js#L643. The PhantomCSS then uses `casper.capture` to get the according sources. I would dig into this direction. Please reply if this was helpful or might be improved. BackstopJS also depends on Casper, so it's worth checking it. If no API provided - only dirty hacker's hands may help you. Let the Force be with you.